# Apache vHost - Optimized and Secure

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I took a look at the [Canonical Topics](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) ServerFault has and sadly the one I was after "Apache vHost" was on the list of unanswered questions.  I found this a little surprising as there are loads of people asking just that question.

Anyway, my question isn't so much about "how" but rather what are the "best practises" to use in a Virtual Host configuration file?  I have the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/webmaster/examplesite.com/htdocs
    ErrorLog /home/webmaster/examplesite.com/logfiles/error.log
    CustomLog /home/webmaster/examplesite.com/logfiles/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It does the job and gets things working, however I wanted to know if I could improve on it.  In particular I would like to make sure that the following issues are dealt with:

- How secure is my site?
- I would like to have an "uploads" folder where users can post images to.  Do I need to add something to the vHost file?
- Does the above setting optimise my website, or can I optimise it further?
- Anything else I may have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How secure is my site?

Storing your logfiles so they are potentially publically accessible is a bad idea. Error message printing should be off in production, so attackers are blind (they can't use error messages against you[1]). With access to the error logs, they have a stronger chance of trial and error.

> I would like to have an "uploads" folder where users can post images to. Do I need to add something to the vHost file?

You want to place uploads *outside* the document root, to reduce the chance that a user can upload a script (e.g. PHP) and then browse to it, and run it. Naturally this isn't the only protection you should have, but it's certainly one of the components.

> Does the above setting optimise my website, or can I optimise it further?

You can't really optimise your website that much with a vhost - that's Apache level configuration (outside the scope of this question.)

> Anything else I may have missed?

It's difficult to tell, to be honest. Everyone has different requirements. For example, if your website is `example.com` - would you expect `www.example.com` to work too? If so, you're missing a `ServerAlias`.

[1] Imagine they could generate an 'invalid SQL' error. The they know they have found an input which is not cleaned, and have quickly found a way to break into your website. The worst part is: these kinds of attacks can be automated.

Comment: How will the log files be publicly accessible, if they are outside the DocumentRoot?  Does the attacker "trick" apache into serving them anyway?